# Use a texture in line drawing in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript, drawing

I would like to draw line, just like the graphics API, only that it will be assembled of chunks of a given texture ("lineChunk.png")

The chunk would be small to allow rotating it when needed, by the line's path.

The purpose is to let the user, using mouseMove, create a textured line.

I've tried to make it 'manually', but when drawing fast, the distance between two point is vast, and therefore there was a need to close the gap using a while loop, which slowed things down significantly.

The 'graphics.lineBitmapStyle' wasn't helpful as well as it doesn't serve this purpose.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Ever able to figure this out? I'm looking for an answer to the same question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the best way is to create a single Bitmap instance of the sample texture, and create another empty Bitmap which will be your canvas.

Do the regular drill with looping to fill the missing gaps between 2 points, and use Bitmap.Draw to draw in each time the single texture Bitmap after it was transformed of course.

It works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Set graphics line style as:

```
lineBitmapStyle(bitmapData);
```

This specifies a bitmap to use for the line stroke when drawing lines.

[ActionScript 3.0 Reference for Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineBitmapStyle%28%29)

[image: line bitmap style]

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class X extends Sprite
    {
        protected var bitmapData:BitmapData;

        protected var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        public function X()
        {
            super();

            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("lineChunk.png"));
        }

        protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            bitmapData = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;

            var g:Graphics = graphics;
            g.lineStyle(10);
            g.lineBitmapStyle(bitmapData);

            g.moveTo(0, 0);
            g.lineTo(100, 100);
            /* ... */
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've stated that this function is not what I'm looking for...
In your example, as you can see, the white dots are not ordered by the line. I want a drawing function which I can give it one texture of a dot, and it will order and loop it as the line was drawn.